# Logo only showing in Safari

Tags: wordpress, safari

I've been scratching my head for the last 40 minutes trying to figure out why the logo on the below site is only working in Safari.

http://www.jaygeorge.co.uk/catalyst-jrshairdressing/

The logo should be in the top left. The site is a WordPress site and the code I've used to drag in the logo is here:

```
<a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>/"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory') ?>/img/logo.png" alt="JR's Hairdressing" title="JR's Hairdressing" /></a>
```

If you hover over the logo and copy the image link you'll see that the link is correct.

Comment: In Safari and Chrome I get a blank image. If I view it in Firefox, I get an error: "The image “`http://www.jaygeorge.co.uk/catalyst-jrshairdressing/wp-content/themes/catalystjr/img/logo.png`” cannot be displayed, because it contains errors."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the image file itself is the issue. Try the normal bad-image troubleshooting stuff: Open and resave it. Make sure it's RGB. Try a gif instead, etc.

Comment: Yep, you're right, just tried changing it to a different .png and it worked. Will try and correct it now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell what's actually causing the error, but I've found in situations like this simply opening the image in Paint/Photoshop/Gimp, re-saving it and re-uploading usually fixes the problem.